# Keep values of AutoCompleteTextView from resetting upon orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-layout, google-places-api, android-orientation

I'm making my first android app, and I have an AutoCompleteTextView with suggestions shown from the Google Places API. When an item is selected from the suggestions, I have more info about it shown below. This works fine, but when the screen orientation is changed, the values keep disappearing, as if no item had been selected. If I select another item, the suggestions show up fine, but is there any way to keep the values of my TextViews and AutoCompleteTextView when screen orientation is changed?

Answer (score 2):

You just store your selected item in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and load it on onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final String KEY = "save key";
    int mSelectedItemIndex = -1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSelectedItemIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY);
        }

        if (mSelectedItemIndex != -1) {
            // bind selected item to AutoCompleteTextView
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Save your current index
        if (mSelectedItemIndex != -1) {
            outState.putInt(KEY, mSelectedItemIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your Activity in manifest

```
android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

as

```
<activity android:name=".youractivityname"
              android:label="youractivityname"
              android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```